# Total Sales by Segment, not by Product DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

This is my problem, I calculated a *TotalNetOrder* measure, for the example I display the data by Segment (Right table), but when I display the data for Segment/Product granularity (Left Table), **I need keep** *TotalNetOrder* by Segment, not by Product.

This is my DAX measure:

```
TotalSegment = 

VAR MY_TABLE = 
SUMMARIZE(
    T_PRODUCT, 
    T_PRODUCT[Segment],
    "TotalNetOrder", [Total Net Order]

RETURN

CALCULATE(
    SUMX(MY_TABLE, [TotalNetOrder]), ALL(T_PRODUCTSegment)
)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KweWZ.png)

Answer (score 1):

add this measure adjusted to your table and column names...

```
Total Order By Segment =
CALCULATE (
    SUMX ( T_PRODUCT, T_PRODUCT[Net Order] ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( T_PRODUCT, T_PRODUCT[Segment ] )
)
```

[Sample PBix File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/165VXgD-kXid-6S83bo-mvLOggl6B9NlX/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Try this measure:

```
TotalSegment = 
CALCULATE(
    [Total Net Order],
    ALL(T_PRODUCT[BrandName], T_PRODUCT[ProductCode])
)
```

Inside ALL() you may list all the columns you don`t want to be used in calculation. This way is much easier to read and calculate and leads to desired result. At least, with my dummy data:

| BrandName | Segment | ProductCode | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Brand1 | A | 1 | 100 |
| Brand1 | B | 2 | 200 |
| Brand1 | B | 3 | 150 |
| Brand2 | B | 4 | 250 |
| Brand2 | C | 5 | 100 |
| Brand2 | A | 6 | 200 |

```
Total Net Order = 
SUM(T_PRODUCT[Price])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can test this measure:

```
TotalSegment =
VAR My_Table =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        VALUES ( T_PRODUCT[Segment] ),
        "TotalNetOrder", CALCULATE ( SUM ( T_PRODUCT[Total Net Order] ) )
    )
RETURN
    SUMX ( My_Table, [TotalNetOrder] )
```